# Paypal integration in Hybris

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, sap-commerce-cloud, adyen

I want to integrate a third-party payment provider i.e. Paypal into Hybris. I have installed Adyen extension and its addon. What are the further steps for paypal integration?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Adyen has an official guide for integrating Adyen with SAP Commerce: https://docs.adyen.com/plugins/hybris

You can integrate two ways:

- Web Drop-in: an all-in-one solution, the quickest way to accept payments on your website
- Web Components: one Component per payment method and combine with your own payments form logic

Adyen documentation on PayPal: https://docs.adyen.com/payment-methods/paypal

Sample integrations: https://github.com/adyen-examples

Comment: What custom changes should I make in controller for adyncheckout addon ?